# Error 405- Method Not allowed WCF file upload with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, file-upload

I have created an MVC website  that uses a WCF web service for file uploads. (Using Asp.net developer server) at the moment.(I'm quite new to WCF)
The web service is configured  to use a "POST" i.e  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST"] 
However, I keep getting  Error 405 after numerous tries and time spent browsing the web. 
I presume this might be something to do with settings in the web.config file. 
I just need to be clear on the exact settings to enable this work.

Here's my service contract

[ServiceContract]

```
   public interface IFileUpload
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "FileUpload/{session}/{fileName}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        bool Upload(string session, string fileName, Stream stream);


    }
```

Comment: put your code inside a {code sample} block